# Mapbox using flutter

Tags: flutter, mapbox-gl

I want to integrate mapbox using flutter
The thing I am doing is just installing my sdk in pubsec.yaml and placing the access token in Android Manifest file and Info.plist

Here is my pubsec.yaml where I am adding mapbox_gl

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  mapbox_gl: ^0.0.3
```

I have not yet added any code in dart file and just trying to run the application but it gives me the error

```
/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mapbox_gl-0.0.3/android/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxgl/MapboxMapController.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                          ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: package androidx.annotation
/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mapbox_gl-0.0.3/android/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxgl/MapboxMapController.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
  private static String getAccessToken(@NonNull Context context) {
                                        ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class MapboxMapController
/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mapbox_gl-0.0.3/android/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxgl/MapboxMapController.java:298: error: cannot find symbol
  private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style style) {
                                        ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class MapboxMapController
/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mapbox_gl-0.0.3/android/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxgl/MapboxMapController.java:315: error: cannot find symbol
  private void enableSymbolManager(@NonNull Style style) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class MapboxMapController
/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mapbox_gl-0.0.3/android/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxgl/MapboxMapController.java:326: error: cannot find symbol
  private void enableLineManager(@NonNull Style style) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class MapboxMapController
/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mapbox_gl-0.0.3/android/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxgl/MapboxMapController.java:333: error: cannot find symbol
  private void enableCircleManager(@NonNull Style style) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class MapboxMapController
/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mapbox_gl-0.0.3/android/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxgl/MapboxMapController.java:556: error: cannot find symbol
  public boolean onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
                             ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class MapboxMapController
/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mapbox_gl-0.0.3/android/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxgl/MapboxMapController.java:286: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                               ^
  symbol: class NonNull
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
8 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mapbox_gl:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 4s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
*******************************************************************************************
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you show me pubsec.yaml.

Comment: how you are adding mapbox gl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an AndroidX compatibility issue.

Add this to your `android/gradle.properties` and try to build again:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

([Official docs about AndroidX migration on Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility))